# Add items in a listpicker .. errors

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listpicker

```
string cstring = e.Result;
            string[] delim = {"<br>","*"};
            string[] cstringl = cstring.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.None);
            for (int i = 0; i < cstringl.Length; i++)
            {
                country_picker.Items.Add(cstringl[i]);
            }
```

I am using the above mentioned code to add items in a listbox named country picker, but i get indexoutofrange exception. Why am i getting this error when i have checked the length using i<=cstring1.Length

Comment: It works on try catch... but few items go missing

Comment: what line doe the error occur on? Are there any events hooked up to the ListPicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 issues with your code.

Update it as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cstringl.Length; i++) 
{ 
    country_picker.Items.Add(cstringl[i]); 
}
```

The 2 changes are:

1. the comparision in the for loop to be "less than" the length, not "less than or equal to" as this will trigger an off by oe error due to Length being the count but the array being zero indexed. This is th cause of your IndexOutOfRangeException.
2. Using the loop variable as an index reference when adding the item. So you don't get the same (first) item added multiple times.

**Update**
Having looked at your code again, another possible issue could be caused by theinitial value of `e.result`. Try using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` so you don't risk trygin to enter empty values. Also add a check that `cstringl` contains at least one item.

Comment: As edited i have used i for refrence, and less than in place of less than equal to.. error still persists.. but still index out of range errors exists.

Comment: You sure? because < should be enough. You did a recompile?

Comment: i have solved this problem by running loop upto length -1 because the last entry is a white space..or should i say it just worked and i dont know how :p .. please i have posted a new Q check if you can help there too thanks..